# Swift - Interactive onboarding while using the app

Tags: ios, swift, user-experience

Pardon the novice question!

After our users create an account and have successfully come into our app, I want to create an onboarding experience that is interactive but simple, using gestures/hints. A way for us to say: "Click this thumbs up to send a like", "Swipe up to do X".

These suggestions should only show up for the very first time the user joins the app and never again. Are there any tutorials or anything I could look at to figure this out? I've only seen tutorials on traditional onboarding experience (intro-swipe screens).

Would love general thoughts or tips on where I could look into to figure this out. The design work is less the issue, it's more so figuring the mechanics of it being "onboarding" and not coming back again.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

What I typically do for first-time runs is set a UserDefaults Bool for a "firstRun" or "onboardingComplete" key. When you register the UserDefaults, you set it to true/false, and then after the user completes the onboarding, you toggle it.

Do a quick if/then on that UserDefaults key on app launch and run a "handleFirstRun" function if needed.